# HQL doesn't extract results with null fields

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, entitymanager

I want to retrieve all tuples from a Table even if containing null fields, using HQL. The logic is explained as follows:

"If a particular field is null returns the tuple, instead, if it's not null, check the 'where' clause of the query."

I tried to write the query like this, but actually it doesn't work.

```
String query ="FROM Audit t WHERE (t.emp IS NULL OR t.emp.name LIKE '%')";
listaServer = entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

Here is the Audit table

```
| ID | EMP    | STATE  |
***********************
|  1 | 150    | Active |
|  2 | (null) | Active |
```

and this is the Emp table

```
| ID | Name  |
**************
|150 | Tom   |
|151 | John  |
```

When I run the query, it returns only the first tuple of the Audit table. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont have a required HQL. I think you are going to need a  inner join when there is an association between entities. So I would suggest below query

```
select a from Audit a join a.emp e where e is not null  OR emp.name LIKE '%'
```

Which should go like

```
String query ="select a from Audit a join a.emp e where e is not null  OR emp.name LIKE '%'";
listaServer = entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

Comment: Rather than an inner join with a 'where' clause that checks for not empty fields , I should use a left outer join to return tuples with empty fields. How can I do a left join in hibernate without encountering the following exception?
ORA-25156: old style outer join (+) cannot be used with ANSI joins

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, it is because this expression: `t.emp.name LIKE '%'`
To evaluate this expression the hibernate will generate an inner join.
You should try to define a left outer join between the tables, and run the select in that scope.
Something like this:

```
SELECT t from Audit t LEFT JOIN t.emps e WHERE (t.emp IS NULL OR e.name LIKE '%')
```

Comment: I tried like you suggested me but I have this exception:

ORA-25156: old style outer join (+) cannot be used with ANSI joins

Comment: Use ON instead of WHERE in JOIN, WHERE is deprecated